# compare values from db to String

Tags: java, android

I try to compare data from db to String but its not valid...
I put to db few informations, one int for time and few Strings. Then i get information from db and store them as table and show on ListView. Now I try to compare the values to show specyfic data. I know values in my table/db so I try:

```
if (value[i][2] == "Plain"){
}
```

But it's don't work. So i Try:

```
if (value[i][2] != "Plain"){
}
```

And i get full list also with items where `value[i][2] == "Plain"`. I also make toast when `OnItemClickListener and show`value[i][2]`on it so I'm 100% sure`value[i][2]` it's Plain

Then I try:

```
String PlainTest = value[i][2];
if (value[i][2] == PlainTest){
}
```

And again it's correct...
I also try `value[i][2].trim()` but still nothing
Any idea what else I can check? I know value I get from db. I can show it on list, I can show it on toast. But somehow i can't compare it to string
I don't get any errors. It's just like values don't match

Comment: Use `equals` rather than `==`

Comment: see this post [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
value[i][2].equals("Plain")
```

Answer (score 1):

To compare strings use the `equals` method

`value[i][2].equals("Plain")`

Comment: Thanks... 2hr of searching and it's so simple :/

Comment: :( Search on SO first there are lots of useful answers around

Comment: Yea i search here but i don't search compare strings. I search only compare values from db to string and don't get solid answer. My fault i should search deeper :)

Comment: Never mind, lesson learnt for next time! Make sure you read the links in the question comments

Comment: @Spun to explain this, since strings are objects, they are only == if they not only contain the same characters but ALSO refer to the same object in memory. if they reference different memory locations, then they are not ==. this messes up a LOT of beginners because when you write little test programs, Java will often reuse Strings from memory, meaning == comes out true. .equals compares the contents only, and so it is more reliable.

Comment: @Jeff this is all covered in the links in question comments

Comment: @cowls most folks don't bother with links once they get their answer ;)

Comment: I do and read it already :)

Answer (score 0):

use `equals` to compare string

```
String PlainTest = value[i][2];
if (value[i][2].equals(PlainTest)) {
}
```